# Refactor from mapstatetoprops to hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I was refactoring React legacy code which uses class component and came across the mapstatetoprops function looking like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  getProductById: (id) => getProductById(state, id),
  selectedOutletId: getSelectedOutletId(state),
});
```

And what I wanted to do is to convert mapstatetoprops into hooks useSelector. So, I faced the problem with conversion of `getProductById: (id) => getProductById(state, id)`, that is, in hooks I converted it into

```
const productById =(id) =>useSelector((state)=>getProductById(state, id))
```

but it says that

> React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "productById" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: I'm a bit confused as how the `getProductById` is called from class component. Can you share how or where it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need a different hooks for converting `getProductById: (id) => getProductById(state, id),`. As the warning suggests, you cannot call the `useSelector` in a function since it is a custom hook. You may want to try to use the `useStore` hooks.

First, you need to import the hook.
`import { useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux'`.

Then, on your React function component body.

```
function YourComponent(props) {
  const store = useStore()
  const selectedOutletId = useSelector(state => getSelectedOutletId(state))
  const productById = (id) => getProductById(store.getState(), id)
}
```